# Running a simple JBDC program from command prompt

Tags: java, jdbc

Need some assistance on running a simple jdbc program from command prompt.

Tried different methods but not able to success in running it.

My system environment variables are i.e.

user variables:

```
path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin
```

My jbdc program is present in `D:\JDBC\A.java`

and path of my Oracle jar file is:

```
D:\Oracle_10G\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar
```

can some one help me out to run this and setting the `ojdbc14.jar` as `classpath` would be great full.

Comment: **What error do you get**?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile:

`D:\JDBC>javac -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;D:\Oracle_10G\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar "A.java`

To run:

`D:\JDBC>java -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;D:\Oracle_10G\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar;." A`

Best of luck and if you should have further problems, let me know.

Comment: D:\JDBC>javac -cp C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;D:\Oracle_10G\app\
oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar A.java
javac: invalid flag: (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;D:\Oracle_10G\app\oracle\product
\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: yeap it works fine. Now how do I set these in the environmental Variables.

Comment: Oh, yea, for goodness sakes, I hope you don't name production files after single letters of the alphabet. :)

Answer (score 0):

point you cmd to D:\JDBC
compile program javac -cp D:\Oracle_10G\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar A.java

run it java -cp D:\Oracle_10G\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar A

Comment: D:\JDBC>javac -C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin D:\Oracle_10G\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar A.java

When I run this it shows the error saying 
javac: invalid flag: C:\Program
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to run JDBC application from Command prompt is set Path's of JDK and Database's jar file as follows:

Right click on My Computer->Properties->In left pane, Click on Advanced System Settings->Click on Environment Variables

In Environment Variables window, add 2 new entries in System variables:

**SET CLASSPATH**

Click on New...->Set Variable name -- CLASSPATH and Set Variable value -- C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.J 5.1\mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar
-> Ok

Variable value may be different for different computers so adjust path as per your system configuration

Also specify your project's path in class path value.